# Modifing the Date/Time Stamp of an email message using a Lotus Notes Agent

Tags: lotus, agent, datestamp

I've created an agent that copies messages from one folder to another, which works great, but I'd like to modify the Time/Date stamp on the message.

I see a value Date in the Simple Action, but can't find the variable to set the time to "now".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use formula @Now but you can't modify the date you see in the first tab of document properties, you can only edit the field in the document.